# Rspec fails when it needs to open up a popup on click function in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

In my application , when i click  href(hyperlink), popup should open up and test the features. In all the places where there is on click event for a link, all Rspecs test cases are failing to open the modal window. i am using below gems. i am runnning the Rspecs inside docker -Centos image. It was working early . We made few changes in the application like adding few css. After those changes ,all onclick Rspecs is failing. Can anyone help? Ruby version is 2.3

```
  rspec-expectations 3.4.0
  rspec-mocks 3.4.1
  rspec 3.4.0
  rspec-rails 3.4.2
  rspec_junit_formatter 0.2.3
  selenium-webdriver 3.9.0
  capybara 2.7.1
  rails 4.2.6
```

Sample HTML code for link

```
  <%= link_to 'Contact Us', '/contactus',  {:id=> 'submit', :remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#contactusId', :class=>'btn btn-default'}
```

Sample Rspec

```
  require 'rails_helper'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  RSpec.feature 'Contact Us - 'do

    scenario 'create a simple contact request after login with logged in users email id and name' do
      visit '/signin'
      do_login 'test', 'test'
      sleep 5
      click_link('Contact Us', visible: true)
      fill_contact_us_form 'a','b','c','8056286205','From Rspec'
      click_on 'Send Email'
      expect(page).to have_content("Your request has been submitted")
    end

    def fill_contact_us_form(name, companyname, emailid,contactNumber,notes)
      if(name!=nil)
        fill_in 'contact_us_name', :with => name
      end
      fill_in 'contact_us_company_name', :with => companyname
      if(emailid!=nil)
        fill_in 'contact_us_email_id', :with => emailid
      end
      if(contactNumber!=nil)
        fill_in 'contact_us_contact_number', :with => contactNumber
      end
      if(contactNumber!=nil)
        fill_in 'contact_us_notes', :with => notes
      end
    end
```

Error

```
 Contact Us -  create a simple contact request after login with logged in users email id and name
 Failure/Error: fill_in 'contact_us_company_name', :with => companyname
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
 Unable to find field "contact_us_company_name"
```

Comment: If you inspect the element on the link that your test is hoping to click, what does the html/css look like.  More likely than not the markup changed so you can't find the element any longer.

Comment: Your tests aren't tagged with `js: true` metadata - which could mean you're not running with a JS enabled driver (unless you've set the default driver to a JS enabled) - show your Capybara config.  The other thing to do would be to look at the output of `puts page.html` right before the `fill_in 'contact_us_company_name'` and see what's actually on the page.   Other general things are you're running an obsolete version of Capybara, you really should look at statement modifiers rather than the `if (blah!=nil)` blocks, and you should be using visible assertions rather than `sleep` statements.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several factors contributing to the failure. You should check the following:

- The input you're looking does exist. `fill_in` will try to match an input with name, id or label **contact_us_company_name**
- The modal has transitions and take longer than [`Capybara.max_wait_time_out`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara#default_max_wait_time-class_method), so you should set  the `:wait` option
- The scenario is not running javascript, so the modal is never shown.

`fill_in` documentation can be found [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions:fill_in)

Comment: Try running your tests with a javascript enabled. `scenario 'something', js: true do`

Comment: Tried that too it is still failing